# Creating a directory with file.mkdir() is failing

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to create a file and write it to my dir but it's failing and I can't figure out why.

```
private static void workingSave(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        boolean success = myDir.mkdirs();
        Log.d(TAG, "workingSave: " + success);  //Returns false everytime
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing incorrectly

I've added permissions in the manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I've added runtime check permissions for Android M, and they are granted

I've tried adding `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` for Android 10+

I've tried using `.mkdir()` instead of `.mkdirs()`

it still returns false and doesn't create the directory.

I can't figure out why it's not working

**___________________________________________________________**

I threw it into a try catch it doesn't return any errors.

```
private static void createDir(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        try {
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
            boolean success = myDir.mkdirs();
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: " + success);
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: " + e);
        }
    }
```

All it does it returns false for the success flag.

**____________________________________________**

Writing the file to the directory (working):

```
 private static void createDir(Bitmap finalBitmap) {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        if (!myDir.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: Directory does not exist");
            boolean makeDir = myDir.mkdir();
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: is successful making dir: " + makeDir);
        }

        File file = new File(myDir, "603566786B0226BB");

        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: File already exists.");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: File does not exist.");
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                Log.d(TAG, "saveImage: Successfully written image.");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Provide some error logs, please.

Comment: `private static void createDir` Make that `private static boolean createDir` And let the caller check the return value before continuing. `Bitmap finalBitmap` ????

Comment: I made an edit to the post above. All it returns is the boolean success flag for if creating the directory was successful or not. ```createDir: false```. The exception block is not called. ```boolean success = myDir.mkdirs();``` is returning that success flag.

Comment: Who is returning that success flag? You could do that was my suggestion.

Comment: And you are using an Android 10 or 11 device.

Comment: The ```File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");``` returns ```/storage/emulated/0/saved_images``` from logging it. I'm using a Pixel 2 API 27, on Android 8.1

Comment: `String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
` Replace by:             `File myDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "saved_images");`

Comment: mkdirs() and mkdir() return false if the directory does already exist. So you should only call them if the directory does not exist yet. `if (!myDir.exists(){ ....call mkdir or mkdirs...}`

Comment: `The exception block is not called. ` Correct. Those functions do not throw. You can better remove the try-catch.

Comment: Ah okay, it says the directory already exists when I use ```myDir.exists()```. I've also used ```file.exists()``` to check for if my file exists inside that directory, and it also says the file exists, but I don't see it in the directory.

Comment: I can load that image path with glide, and it works. @blackapps thanks for all your help. Could you please write a quick answer so I could mark it as correct?

Comment: `boolean makeDir = myDir.mkdir();
            Log.d(TAG, "createDir: is successful making dir: " + makeDir);
 ` No. no, no. You are crying success without checking the return value of mkdir. And worse you are continuing to make a file if the directory is not created. Better: `if (!file.exists())  if (!file.mkdirs()) return;`